# Get the message of a java throwable in a string

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to create an error handler that will take an error message and print it to the logging file. Is there a way I can get the massage if I use a try/catch like this?

```
try{
    //code;
}catch(Exception e){
   Main.error=e.?;
}
```

I have tried e.getMessage() but it only returns null. Thanks in advance

Comment: An exception doesn't necessarily have to have a message.

Comment: There a various libraries for logging purposes like java.util.logging or log4j

Comment: It is [questionable whether you should report the message text of exceptions for exceptions that do not indicate bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320080/should-you-report-the-message-text-of-exceptions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage%28%29) of the Throwable class (Where getMessage() comes from):

> Returns:
>       the detail message string of this Throwable instance (**which may be null**).

Thus a null message is a perfectly legal response from getMessage() and is created whenever the Exception class is instantiated with no arguments.

If by message, you mean the *Stack Trace*, then Throwable defines a [getStackTrace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29) method, which allows you to iterate through the various elements that would be printed in a `printStackTrace`, from which you can get their string output just using `toString()`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
try{
//code;
}catch(Exception e){
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
      writer.println(e.toString());
      writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `e.toString()`?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it only returns the error type, not the traceback.

Comment: If you want to print the stack traceback, you can use `e.getStackTrace()`.