# IOException message not printed correctly when using Java 9 on Windows 10 set to Japan locale and language

Tags: windows-10, locale, ioexception, java-9, cjk

An Exception is thrown in this particular block.

```
   try
   {
       transport.m_readListener.onReadTransport(transport);
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
       ->onIOException(e,transport);
   }
```

The onIOException() method puts it on the log:

```
    private void onIOException(IOException e, AbstractConnection connection)
    {
        String reason = e.getMessage();
        ...
        log.error("Closing ",connection," because ",reason);
    }
```

The reason variable in Java 8 shows a correct japanese phrase:

> reason : **既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました**。
>   (meaning: The existing connection was forcibly disconnected to the remote host)

When ran on Java 9, the exception message is now broken:

> reason : **譌｢蟄倥?ｮ謗･邯壹?ｯ繝ｪ繝｢繝ｼ繝? 繝帙せ繝医↓蠑ｷ蛻ｶ逧?縺ｫ蛻?譁ｭ縺輔ｌ縺ｾ縺励◆縲**?

The code block that checks if the Socket port is still open is inside a try catch block that catches the IOException. The message from the IOException is acquired via

```
    String reason = e.getMessage();
    if (null == reason) reason = e.toString();
```

Tried running the app with **java.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR,SPI** to make it behave like in Java 8 but nothing happens. Anyone has an idea on this issue? Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Could you also update the question with the piece of code to reproduce this?

Comment: Can you update the question with the stack trace? I can't tell from the question if the issue is the exception message or how it printed to the console.

Comment: The issue is the way it is printed to the console.

Comment: On java 8, even if Windows is in Japan locale and set to Japanese language, the IOException message is printed correctly in Japanese.

Comment: However, it is questionable whether to report the message text of exceptions to users: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320080/should-you-report-the-message-text-of-exceptions

Comment: Displayed to the client or not, the problem is that the message from the IOException is garbled. Anyone else has an idea regarding this matter?

Comment: Have you try using String.format(Locale.JAPAN, e.toString()); ?
There are so many places where the locale can be overridden, it's hard to pinpoint without a minimal, complete, verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Karis are you referring to String​(byte[] bytes, String charsetName) or String​(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)? String.format is a different method for formatting.

Comment: @Karis you cannot format a string like that, it's not a format template `%3.2f %s etc`