# When is it OK to use an Enum's name()

Tags: java, enums, anti-patterns

Variables' name can be changed and shouldn't affect logic. But `name()` method in Enum returns a constant name as a value so it can break existing code. Should I avoid using `name()`?

For example,

```
public enum Example1 {FOO, BAR}
```

Refactoring `FOO` name to `FOO2` will brake `Example1.FOO.name().equals("FOO")`.

```
public enum Example2 {
    FOO("FOO"),
    BAR("BAR");

    String code;

    private Example2(final String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

In this case, changing `FOO` name to `FOO2` will not brake `Example2.FOO.getCode().equals("FOO")`.

Comment: What would you write `Example1.FOO.name().equals("FOO")` for?

Comment: The `name()` method returns the name of the enumeration value. If you want a readable string, use `toString()` (that by default returns the name).

Comment: `But name() method in Enum returns a variable name as a value so it can break existing code.` Do you think you can change the name of "FOO"?

Comment: @ruakh reading values from URL parameters for example

Comment: In that case, you should consider using a *switch-case*

Comment: @JudeNiroshan That can be right in a case. But in my case, I only need to know whather or not the value is "FOO".

Comment: I avoid using `.name()` given what is written in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name())

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Business logic** should use the **enum value**, never the `name()` directly. Reason: even if the name changes, the semantic (same enum value as before) remains the same.
- The `name()` is used when **serializing/deserializing** values. This affects the database (when using the names for O/R mapping), serialized data stored in files or transmitted over the wire (JSON/XML/YAML/... serialization), log entries and more. 
  Changing the name might require data migration or adaptions in 3rd party code.

Comment: Is the same applied to `valueOf` and `toString` method?

Comment: valueOf is directly coupled to the name, and neither name() nor valueOf() can be overridden, so: yes. toString, on the other hand, can be overridden and be used to display additional information / fields of the enum.

Answer (score 2):

Your suspicion that it is unwise to use it generally because it leaks an implementation detail is correct. If you had a colour `enum` with a `RED` value, it would be wrong to report to a program user the colour of something using `colour.name()`, because the user might need a message in a language other than English, and ALL CAPS text would usually be inappropriate.

Using it in code used by programmers to help debug problems is OK. Such as exception messages, because [they should not be presented to normal program users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320104/545127).

Answer (score -2):

When using enum type, I always compares enum itself but not enum's name(string).

```
Example2.FOO.equals(Example2.getEnumByName("FOO"));
```

Comment: I got string values from URL parameters. It can be converted to an enum value, but parameters are so easy to be tempered by clients. So I choose to compare strings in this case.

Comment: The question is about renaming an enum constant in the source code (AKA refactoring it) without breaking any code that relied on that name. Here, the code would be broken in the same way as when using `Example1.FOO.name().equals("FOO")`.